# jQuery - Get value of hidden input from previous TD in table

Tags: jquery

Im kinda stuck and have browsed numerous of pages here on stackoverflow to find a solution.

I have a invoice table where you can dynamicly add new TR with input fields. 
This works fine but on the first and second input fields.

The first autocomplete input field is based on the customers ID.
However, the second autocomplete is based on the first autocomplete selected value which adds a value to a hidden input field (an ID).

The second autocomplete works oke, but i have to get the value of the last hidden input field in the previous TD of the table.

the class of each TR row is class=".item-row". The second autocomplete is located in the second TD of the table.

Im using the following script:

```
   // Use the .autocomplete() method to compile the list based on input from user
   $(".articleName").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
    var $itemrow = $(this).closest('tr');
        $.ajax({
            url: "getproducts-test.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term: request.term,
                staffid: $itemrow.find('#debiteuren_staffmembers_id').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var $itemrow = $(this).closest('tr');
                // Populate the input fields from the returned values
                $itemrow.find('#articleName').val(ui.item.articleName);
                $itemrow.find('#articleSize').val(ui.item.articleDescription);
                $itemrow.find('#articlePrice').val(ui.item.articlePrice);

                // Give focus to the next input field to recieve input from user
                $('#articleQty').focus();

        return false;
    }
// Format the list menu output of the autocomplete
}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.articleName + " - " + item.articleDescription + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Where u can see i need the ID to get the correct values returned.
This is what is not working:

```
staffid: $itemrow.find('#debiteuren_staffmembers_id').val()
```

This the HTML for example:

```
<tr class="item-row">
<td>
   <textarea name="debiteuren_staffmembers[]" id="debiteuren_staffmembers"></textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="debiteuren_staffmembers_id[]" id="debiteuren_staffmembers_id" value="2">
</td>
<td>
   <textarea name="articleName[]" id="articleName"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
```

If for example i change the code to get the staffid to this:

```
staffid: $('#debiteuren_staffmembers_id').val()
```

It works, but it will only get the value of the FIRST hidden input from the first ROW in the table and i need the input from the current row where the autocomplete is beeing used.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could shine some light. Thank you all.

Comment: What type of element is `#debiteuren_staffmembers_id`? is the id unique?

Comment: are you using debiteuren_staffmembers_id as an ID for multiple elements?

Comment: Its a <input type="hidden" name="debiteuren_staffmembers_id" id="debiteuren_staffmembers_id">



@ Igarioshka: No, i just save the staffmember ID in those inputs because i need them for the second autocomplete field to get the list of clothing based on that staffmember and i save the ID of the staffmember in the database once the invoice is saved.

The staffmembers id is getting populated by the first autocomplete.

Comment: could you post an example html generated?

Comment: I have added the HTML to the post. But i think the problem does not lie in the HTML...

Comment: @Adriaan and you dynamically add the rows like that to the table?

Comment: @Igarioshka No, the rows beeing added dynamicly with a other function. But these all work the way they should. When i add a new row and bind the autocomplete to the new field i use this staffid: $(".item-row:last").find("#debiteuren_staffmembers_id").val()  to get the last input value, which works fine offcourse because its the last row. But when i start editing any fields of rows above the last row it uses the code from my post offcourse, to get the current values of that specific row im editing.

Comment: `I have a invoice table where you can dynamicly add new TR with input fields.` Well this is adding that you have a invalid markup with same ids for multiple inputs elements and when it happens it only gets the first one.

Comment: @Jai No its valid markup. Everything works fine, also with adding new invoices, its just only this that doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

judging from the question and the conversation, you are using

```
id="debiteuren_staffmembers" //etc...
```

for multiple elements. try to use clases for multiple elements in your markup, or some other attributes because is not valid HTML, in the DOM values of id attribute must be unique, that's why you can not get the value.

**UPD**

your `$(this)` keyword is not referencing the `$(".articleName")` input field. it references the auto-complete object. you need to look for a method to find the input field.

for example, you could use:

```
$(".articleName").each(function(index, value){
  var $that = $(this);
  $(this).autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
      var $itemrow = $that.closest('tr');
      ....
});
```

either check the documentation of the autocomplete plug-in you are using, for a reffference to the input object.

Comment: I have already tried it by adding a class="debiteuren_staffmembers_id"  and using staffid: $(this).closest('tr').find('.debiteuren_staffmembers_id').val()

this also does not get me the value.

Comment: could you look up the value of `this` in the source function, in the developer tools (F12 in browsers like IE chrome)?

Comment: How do i do that, do i have to type in the console $(this) ?

Comment: you can add a break point at code runtime. as an example, here's a reference to [chrome development tools documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). when the breakoinp is hit, then you may type $(this) in the console, or just look at the local variables.

Comment: [
b.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)
_renderItem: function ( ul, item ) {
element: c.fn.c.init[1]
menu: b.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)
options: Object
previous: "Jack"
response: function (){return a._response.apply(a,arguments)}
searching: 4
selectedItem: null
source: function (request, response) {
term: "Ja"
__proto__: b.Widget

Comment: Thank you so much Igarioshka! That was a life saver! You're the best, 100 million thanks brother!